# Automatic line break in WPF label

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, line-breaks

Is it possible for a WPF `Label` to split itself automatically into several lines? In my following example, the text is cropped at the right.

```
<Window x:Class="..." xmlns="..." xmlns:x="..." Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label>
            `_Twas brillig, and the slithy toves did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
            all mimsy were the borogoves, and the mome raths outgrabe.
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Taking other controls is unfortunately not a good option, since I need support of access keys.

Replacing the `Label` with a `TextBlock` (having `TextWrapping="Wrap"`), and adjusting its control template to recognize access keys would be perhaps a solution, but isn't it an overkill?

Edit: having a non-standard style for label will break skinning, so I would like to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: Using TextBlock instead of Label seems like the simple solution. Its not overkill if it works and does not significantly increase the size of your code.

Sometimes with WPF, its not clear why certain things exist at all, like why have both Label and TextBlock, when its possible to just use TextBlock in all relevant situations.

Comment: @kmontgom: Indeed `TextBlock` and `Label` are different beasts: see a nice article http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/ about it. I assumed there must be a simpler solution than replacing a control template (because this may break skinning, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Good points. What this tells me is that perhaps the line-break functionality should be added to <Label>, or perhaps <TextBlock> should be a control. I'd go for expanding the capabilities of <Label>

Comment: @kmontgom: you are welcome. As of me, I see no sense, too, in not allowing a label to be somewhat more advanced.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using both Label and TextBlock together seems to be the correct answer.  [There's a howto located here that demonstrates this exact issue.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743266.aspx)

Specifically, in their example, to get wrapping text and an access key:

```
<Label Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Target="{Binding ElementName=textBox1}">
  <AccessText TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
    _Another long piece of text that requires text wrapping
    goes here.
  </AccessText>
</Label>
```

Comment: @Ben: In your answer, s/TextBlock/AccessText/ :-)

Comment: @Vlad, I suspected that was true, but I did copy-paste it from MSDN.  I guess the real answer is to never trust MSDN.  :)

Comment: Yes, it's always better to try first. :)

Comment: Exactly wrong... it's always better to read MSDN first, but then also try yourself.

Step 1: Obtain Knowledge
Step 2: Adapt the knowledge to your situation
Step 3: ???????????
Step 4: Gain advantage (PROFIT)